# <html> cover click function jquery

Tags: jquery, html, click

I'm working on a website, when I try to trigger an event with `click()` [jquery] the page seems don't work. Seems `html` tag cover other tag, i try this script:

```
$("*").click(function(){
    console.log("" + $(this).prop("tagName"));
});
```

And the console show: HTML everywhere I click.

How can i fix this bug? An older version of the website is:
http://www.trottaetrotta.it/newsviluppo/index.php

Comment: Look - http://jsfiddle.net/9ndn2ysf/1/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`event.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

> The DOM element that initiated the event.

```
$("*").click(function(event){
    console.log(event.target.tagName); //event.target.nodeName
});
```

Comment: But console executes more times what reason look fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9ndn2ysf/

Comment: Whit this function i see where i click, but i don't resolve my problem, or i need to parse every click, and if i don't need it, discard

Comment: sorry, my english is very bad.
I need to trigger an event on the element in the middle of the page, but i cant because when i set a click event:

$("section").click(function(){...});

the function not work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cxLbr9x4/

is a fast copy-paste of the site, and i dont understand why dont work

Comment: Right, in jsfiddle work, but not in my site.
I'm uploading the site on:
http://www.trottaetrotta.it/newsviluppo/index.php

why here not work?

Comment: @Barone, Wrap your code in `$(function() {
});` document-ready handler